# How do i setup OpenDNS family shield?

Tags: 15.04, internet, opendns

I am using ubuntu 15.04 with a mobile broadband connection, i want to setup OpenDNS family shield on it.

Comment: you want to  manually add dns server to your connection as in make it your main DNS resolver

Comment: I am not sure how to do that

Answer (score 1):

manually add dns server to your connection as in make it your main DNS resolver.

click on the connection icon located at the top right hand corner.

[image]

1. Then click on edit connections.
2. Then select your connection then click edit.

[image]

Go to `IPv4 Settings` Tab

Switch method to "Automatic (DHCP) addresses only"

[image]

Enter in your DNS Server in the `Additional DNS Servers Field: like so`

[image]

then click save now you are set up with OpenDNS family shield.